# Could a D DLL work within SAS?

Tags: dll, sas, d

I've been reading the [D Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/d-cookbook) and near the beginning there's the following sentence:

> D is binary compatible with C, but not source compatible.

[SAS allows users to define and call C functions from within SAS](http://support.sas.com/kb/40/562.html). But I'm wondering, would it'd also be possible to do this from D?

I found Adam Ruppe's answer to create a DLL [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20690652/3836809), and I tried using that to create the DLL example from the SAS documentation; however, whenever I go to call it, the dll gets loaded, and then SAS proceeds to crash (without any crash log that I can find).

Comment: could be that you declared the functions wrong, the default is not appropriate for this

Comment: That causing SAS to crash wouldn't surprise me; however, I have very limited experience with DLLs, and essentially none within D. I know within SAS they have to be using the __stdcall Gz calling convention, but I'm not sure how to verify this is being done within D.

Comment: The crash is probably missing `extern(Windows)` like CyberShadow said. Just to clarify that sentence though, what I meant there was D can call or make functions callable from C, but it can't read C source code directly. Now, a *lot* of C code will also compile as D, and will mostly do the same thing, but there are some important details to check. `extern` is one of them. Matching types and layouts are important too. With `int` that is easy, a C int and a D int are the same. But passing strings between C and D is a bit trickier so if you try to do that, it is likely to crash too.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe: Thanks for the clarification, and also thanks for the book :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can write DLLs in D which use or implement a C API.

You have to make sure that the function signatures and calling conventions match. In the page you linked, the calling convention is indicated as `stdcall`, so your D functions need to be annotated with `extern(Windows)` or `extern(System)`.

Comment: Thanks! I found [this page](http://dlang.org/attribute.html#linkage) regarding extern after verifying this answer fixed the problem.